# Galaxy S3 graphics issue, how to resolve?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen

My Galaxy S3 has developed a graphics fault (see image) and I don't know the cause or the cure.  It has not been exposed to humidity or any thing magnetic and to the best of my knowledge it has not been dropped.  Im not sure whether its a hardware or an Android OS issue.

The fault is a purplish blemish that seems to be getting darker and bigger with time.  Has any body got any idea of the cause but more importantly the cure (if any).  Many Thanks

[image: photo]

Comment: It must be hardware issue.

Comment: What was the cause of the problem anyway?
What caused the damage?
I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phone officially needs a trip back to a Samsung Service center

That is in **No Way** caused by any android glitch, as the issue is progressive (getting darker, bigger in time). It might be caused by some shock that made the lcd inside crack and bleed.

Comment: Yes,  I sent it back to see whats what